# Trying to build poco-1.8.1-all from source code on openwrt

Tags: linux, openssl, poco, openwrt

```
root@OpenWrt:~/poco-1.8.1-all# ./configure --no-tests --no-samples --omit=CppUnit,Data,MongoDB,PageCompiler,Redis,Zip
root@OpenWrt:~/poco-1.8.1-all# make
In file included from include/Poco/Crypto/CipherKeyImpl.h:22:0,
                 from include/Poco/Crypto/CipherKey.h:22,
                 from src/CipherFactory.cpp:17:
include/Poco/Crypto/OpenSSLInitializer.h:24:10:fatal error: openssl/crypto.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/crypto.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [/root/poco-1.8.1-all/build/rules/compile:52: /root/poco-1.8.1-all/Crypto/obj/Linux/armv6l/debug_shared/CipherFactory.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/poco-1.8.1-all/Crypto'
make: *** [Makefile:201: Crypto-libexec] Error 2
```

p.s. Openssl is installed

p.s.s I tried everything I found in the google

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling for Openwrt, most of the time, you are doing cross-compiling unless your compile within Openwrt. But you are not configure to cross-compile.

FYI of cross compiling
https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html

I checkout that poco project with version 1.8.1 and run the `./configure`. I see there are a couple of options about choosing the target.
Depending on the target machine that you want your binary poco to run. You should do something like: `./configure --config="ARM-LINUX" --library-path="your-toolchain-directory" # with cflags or something else`

Secondly, missing SSL library maybe you are missing to enable openssl in the menuconfig of openwrt. Make sure you have this file in your toolchain `openssl/crypto.h`. And then, reconfigure and try again